# Is there a command in MathJax to make therefore symbol?

Tags: support, mathjax

Can anyone please tell me if there is a command in Mathjax to make three dots in such that they resemble vertices of a triangle, Basically a $therefore$ symbol.

Usually I refer to [this site if i need a reference to Mathjax commands](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but it looks like it doesn't contain this symbol.

Comment: Note also that `\because` produces $\because$ as a counterpart to `\therefore`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$\therefore$` gives:

$$\therefore$$